# how to set min width on each column in jqgrid guriddo

Tags: jqgrid

Im trying newest commercial version jqgrid guriddo and I need something like min-width on column. 
Im trying everything but nothing works fine. 
My header column name is so long and for small devices doesnt display correct. 
I dont want fixed width becouse for bigger devices is grid smaller.

I need dynamic column which cant be lower than min-width but can be only longer.

Comment: Alternative fork of jqGrid - [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, allows to specify min width of `minResizingWidth` option of grid or `autoResizing.minColWidth` in every column. Try to resize "Date" column in [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Guriddo there is a such option called minColWidth, which defines the minimal column width when resizing - look in the [official documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options)

There was a small problem regarding this options, which is fixed now, so you can test its functionality when you get the fixed code [from GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/archive/master.zip)

Thank you very much for your help to find this problem.

Comment: Thank you but I have still problem. Maybe I have wrong options. My options is: {
  "datatype": "json",
  "height": null,
  "width": null,
  "shrinkToFit": false,
  "gridview": true,
  "rowNum": 0,
  "pager": "logbookByDrivesGridPager",
  "viewrecords": true,
  "url": "LogbookByDrivesGridData",
  "colModel": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "autoResizing": {
        "minColWidth": 310
      },
      "formatter": "integer"
    },
    {
      "name": "place",
      "autoResizing": {
        "minColWidth": 310
      },
      "minColWidth": 350
    }
  ]
}

Comment: minColWidth is a global option for all columns, so you will need to set it as grid option. Currently we work on possibility to have such one per each column. It will be added later today. You will be notified about the change.

Comment: We have added new options in colModel - minResizeWidth, which defines minimal resizing width per column. When set this option have higher priority of minColWidth. You can set it now in colModel. The download with the new option is from the [same place](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Works very good when I manually resize columns but after initialize grid columns are sometimes smaller than minResizeWidth. It depends on resolutions. Option is the same like before but with "minResizeWidth" on each column.

Comment: The options does not take in account the initial width, since the width is controlled with the width options and shrinkToFit options. See the docs how this option work.